# delayed_job queue not being processed on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, delayed-job

I'm running a Rails 3 app with delayed_job. The issue I've come across is that though the app is correctly adding jobs to the queue, they are never being processed.

**My Class**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :send_welcome_email

  private

    def send_welcome_email
      UserMailer.delay.welcome_email(self)
    end
end
```

Inspecting things through the Rails console I can see that there are jobs in the queue. I can also see that there have been 0 attempts to perform the jobs. Spinning up a Heroku worker doesn't cause the jobs to be processed.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**Edit: Trying to clear the jobs queue as suggested below I ran `rake jobs:clear` and received the following error**

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Rake::DSL
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:8:in `<class:TaskLib>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:6:in `<module:Rake>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.rake:1:in `<top (requ
ired)>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/tasks.rb:15:in `block in <top (required)>
'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `each'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize_tasks'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:139:in `load_tasks'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/app/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `load'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1991:in `run'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What is `heroku ps` printing?

Comment: also try setting workers to 1 and then checking the `heroku logs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, the problem turned out to be a bug in Rake 0.9.0. As Rails depends on Rake, running `bundle install` after this release of Rake broke my delayed jobs.

The fix is to add `gem 'rake', '0.8.7'` to your gemfile.

More details can be found below...

DHH's tweet: http://twitter.com/dhh/status/71966528744071169

Discussion in rails_admin's issue tracker: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/428

Answer (score 2):

Two options for you:

These two gems watch delayed_jobs queue and automatically 'hires' background workers to process the thread:

- Option 1: https://github.com/michelson/hirefire  (This is what I am using because it supports mongoid)
- Option 2: This branch of delayed_job developed by a heroku engineer has a similar autoscale feature:  https://github.com/pedro/delayed_job/tree/autoscaling

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, but I already have the hirefire gem as part of my project, yet the jobs aren't being processed.

Comment: Did you set the HIREFIRE_EMAIL and HIREFIRE_PASSWORD heroku config settings?  Do you have any exception monitoring going on?  I wonder if an error is being thrown.  Try this -- clear your queue.  Then tail your heroku log, and add something to queue -- see if you get any useful output

Comment: I did set the email and password settings. No exception monitoring set up.

Though I do get a strange error when trying to clear my queue. Adding that to my question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Even though the initial answer wasn't what I was looking for, your questions set me on the right path.

Comment: Glad I can help, Looks like you are new to SO -- I would accept this answer and open a new separate question on your rake issue.  When posting your rake issue -- include the rake code.  But it looks like you either need to have your rake task load the environment (task :mytask => :environment) or require a library referring to 'DSL'

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the delayed_job daemon in the same environment in which the application is running?

Try working the jobs manually using:
`rake RAILS_ENV=development jobs:work`

If you are running your app in production mode then you need to start delayed_job daemon as:
`RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start`

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda a long shot but make sure you are using the same Ruby version on Heroku as you are on your local machine. I had a problem with delayed jobs on Heroku before because of this.