# Heroku + DelayedJob failing at 'rake jobs:work' and 'heroku workers 1'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, heroku, delayed-job

I cannot get queued delayed_jobs to run on my verified heroku account. Here is the breakdown:

When I invoke delayed_job on heroku

```
# tropo_controller.rb in app/controllers
class TropoController < ApplicationController
  require 'lib/event_job'

  ...

  def sms
    Delayed::Job.enqueue(EventJob.new(nil))
```

And then verify that the delayed_job exists

```
$ heroku console
>> Delayed::Job.all

[#<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job id: 2, priority: 0, attempts: 0, handler: "--- !ruby/struct:EventJob \nevent_id: \n", last_error: nil, run_at: "2011-05-30 21:01:24", locked_at: nil, failed_at: nil, locked_by: nil, created_at: "2011-05-30 21:01:24", updated_at: "2011-05-30 21:01:24">]
```

And attempt to start a new worker either this way

```
$ heroku rake jobs:work
Starting job worker

(hangs)
```

or this way

```
$ heroku workers 1
/Users/jaimeohm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails303/gems/heroku-2.2.1/lib/heroku/command.rb:125:in `rescue in run': undefined local variable or method `args' for Heroku::Command:Module (NameError)
    from /Users/jaimeohm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails303/gems/heroku-2.2.1/lib/heroku/command.rb:116:in `run'
    from /Users/jaimeohm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails303/gems/heroku-2.2.1/bin/heroku:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jaimeohm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails303/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
    from /Users/jaimeohm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails303/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
```

It fails. I run `gem update heroku`, reset the DB, and restart the server, and it still fails. I deliberately empty the perform method of the queued job

```
# event_job.rb in app/lib
class EventJob < Struct.new(:event_id)
  def perform
    # empty for now
  end
end
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think the issue comes from "heroku workers 1" failing. I can't find any instance of that not working, from others' posts.

Comment: Someone else ran into a similar issue, which was caused by a bug introduced by a new version of rake. That is *not* my issue and the fix does *not* solve my issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091964/delayed-job-queue-not-being-processed-on-heroku

Comment: `heroku workers 1` not working is unusual. You might try upgrading to ruby-1.9.2-p180 (you are using 1.9.2-p0 per your RVM path). `rvm install 1.9.2-p180`

Comment: I get the same error now, just with 1.9.2-p180 instead. Maybe it's a gem version issue though, I'll try updating / limiting others.

Comment: heroku gem v1.20.1 works and later ones don't for `heroku workers 1` .. I've filed detailed replication steps with heroku support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku has now fixed this bug as of v2.2.2 of the heroku gem.