# How to fix the uninitialized constant Rake::DSL problem on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rake

I am getting errors similar to the ones [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091964/delayed-job-queue-not-being-processed-on-heroku) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085610/rails-rake-problems-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287121/undefined-method-task-using-rake-0-9-0/5290331#5290331), except mine are occuring on [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com):

```
2011-05-30T09:03:29+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command: `rake jobs:work`
2011-05-30T09:03:30+00:00 app[worker.1]: (in /app)
2011-05-30T09:03:30+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-05-30T09:03:33+00:00 app[worker.1]: rake aborted!
2011-05-30T09:03:33+00:00 app[worker.1]: uninitialized constant Rake::DSL
2011-05-30T09:03:33+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:8:in `<class:TaskLib>'
```

The answer in those questions seems to be to specify `gem 'rake', '0.8.7'` because the 0.9 version causes the problem.

When I try to add `gem 'rake', '0.8.7'` to my gemfile and push to Heroku I get this error:

```
Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
You have modified your Gemfile in development but did not check
the resulting snapshot (Gemfile.lock) into version control

You have added to the Gemfile:
* rake (= 0.8.7)
FAILED: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler
! Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler
error: hooks/pre-receive exited with error code 1
To git@heroku.com:my_app.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:my_app.git'
```

My gemfile normally works fine on Heroku. What should I do?

Comment: Did you try the [#3 answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287121/undefined-method-task-using-rake-0-9-0/5290331#5290331) you posted? What happened after making those changes?

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Put this in your Rakefile **above** require 'rake':

```
require 'rake/dsl_definition'
```

Comment: Thank you. That fixed my problems and I didn't know what was going on. (Using the rails installer on windows and deploying to heroku, as a complete beginner.)

Comment: does this solution work on windows because i am still getting the same error - uninitialized constant Rake::DSL

Comment: I got the error deploying to Heroku, which today pulled in rake 0.9.2. Since the original issue was with 0.9.0, maybe the rake version is no longer the problem. Adding the `require` line to the rakefile (and recommitting and re-pushing to github and Heroku) solved it. @David, I'm using Windows with the RoR framework from RailInstaller 1.2.0.

Comment: Well you'll need to update to rake 0.9.2 for this to work. Good luck!

Comment: I get this error when doing rake db:create, "no such file to load -- rake/dsl_definition"

Answer (score 8):

Any time you change your Gemfile, you need to `bundle install` to update your lockfile (Gemfile.lock). The error you're getting on push is not specific to changing the version of rake.

```
bundle install
git commit -a -m "update lockfile"
git push heroku master
```

Note the error message you received:

> You have modified your Gemfile in development but did not check the resulting snapshot (Gemfile.lock) into version control

Comment: You might need to run "bundle update rake" to regenerate Gemfile.lock.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this, finally, after a lot of mucking about. The short version of what I did, missing out the many experiments, was this:

1) change the Gemfile to specify Rake 0.8.7

```
#in Gemfile
gem "rake", "0.8.7"
```

2) Take out a hack that I had previously added to Rakefile based on Stack Overflow question *[Ruby on Rails and Rake problems: uninitialized constant Rake::DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085610/rails-rake-problems-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl)*:

So, my Rakefile is now back to being the standard Rakefile for my app:

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake'

MyApp::Application.load_tasks
```

3) Change Heroku to run my app in Ruby 1.9.2:

```
heroku stack:migrate bamboo-mri-1.9.2 --app myapp
git push heroku master
```

And it seems fine now - the scheduled cron task is running anyway.

EDIT:  It *did* run fine, once, then blew up again next time I pushed something! Arrgh. I think I fixed it now, with the addition of the `delayed_job` gem, based on the conversation *[Don't know how to build task jobs:work](http://groups.google.com/group/heroku/browse_thread/thread/49bd5333071cd0d1)*.

Installing `delayed_job` doesn't seem like a great solution, but it HAS worked, and I might want to use it sometime I guess, especially with Heroku's once-per-hour cron job (which just isn't frequent enough - there are things I'll probably want to run every five minutes). After I installed the `delayed_job` gem I had to do the setup for it, otherwise Heroku complains about the missing `delayed_jobs` table:

```
#add to gemfile
gem 'delayed_job'

#at command line
bundle install
rails g delayed_job
rake db:migrate
git add -A
git commit -a -m "added delayed_job gem"
git push
heroku rake db:migrate --app myapp
heroku restart --app myapp
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a Rails 3.0.11 app, which specified rake version 0.8.7 in the Gemfile to get around the version 0.9.2 Rake::DSL problem.

After I converted the app to Rails 3.2.0 (Heroku Cedar stack), I was having a problem with the worker (a rake task) crashing. I changed "gem 'rake', '0.8.7'" to "gem 'rake'", which bundled rake version 0.9.2.2. The worker stopped crashing with the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by not deleting the `Gemfile.lock` file and is not specific to Heroku. Deleting `Gemfile.lock` should fix this problem, but will lead you straight to another one:

```
To git@heroku.com:tailored-landing-pages.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
manfred@painstation2:~/Desktop/projects/ror/ta/tlp307$ heroku rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
ninitialized constant Rake::DSL
/app/Rakefile:13:in `<class:Application>'
/app/Rakefile:12:in `<module:Tlp307>'
/app/Rakefile:11:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `load'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1991:in `run'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
```

Unfortunately, I haven't found the solution for that problem yet, since downgrading Rake to 0.8.7 doesn't seem to work here. If somebody else has an answer, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: I would never recommend deleting your lockfile.

Comment: Deleting your Gemfile.lock will result in installing all latest versions of all gems on each deploy to heroku (unless you pin all versions in Gemfile).