# uninitialized constant Rake::DSL in Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby, rake, rubygems

I have been working on updating my gem (whm_xml at https://github.com/ivanoats/whm_xml_api_ruby ) to make it work with ruby 1.9.2, latest rubygems, latest bundler, latest rdoc, latest rake. It works fine in 1.8.7 but has the "uninitialized constant Rake::DSL" error only in 1.9.2 . I thought that rake 0.9.2 fixed that but maybe not? I have read a lot on StackOverflow but am still stuck. Any ideas on where to look?

```
ivan:~/Development/ruby/whm_xml_api_ruby [git:master+]  → bundle exec rake -T
(in /Users/ivan/Development/ruby/whm_xml_api_ruby)
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Rake::DSL
/Users/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2482:in `const_missing'
/Users/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:8:in `<class:TaskLib>'
/Users/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:6:in `<module:Rake>'
/Users/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rdoc-3.6.1/lib/rdoc/task.rb:37:in `require'
/Users/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rdoc-3.6.1/lib/rdoc/task.rb:37:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ivan/Development/ruby/whm_xml_api_ruby/Rakefile:3:in `require'
/Users/ivan/Development/ruby/whm_xml_api_ruby/Rakefile:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `load'
/Users/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in    `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1991:in `run'
/Users/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181312/how-to-fix-the-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl-problem-on-heroku) might help you out. The suggestion there is to add `require 'rake/dsl_definition'` above `require 'rake'` in your `Rakefile`.

Answer (score 3):

<s>I think this is something that happened with the rake 0.9.0 release. Try putting this in your Gemfile: `gem 'rake', '0.8.7'`</s>

**Update**

You could try adding

```
include Rake::DSL if defined?(Rake::DSL)
```

to your app; it worked for my Rails app at one point.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. rake 0.9.2 was supposed to correct this. Also, I want my gem to work with all the latest versions if possible.

Comment: Sorry, I had skimmed over your answer and didn't realize you were aware of that. I updated my answer to try a different method.

Answer (score 3):

I fooled around with the include Rake::DSL, etc and just got other errors.

adding

gem 'rake', '0.8.7'

to the Gemfile seems to work for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with 0.9.1, installed the 0.9.2 and it worked but the db:migrate command sent a message WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please....
it got solved adding to the rake file
module ::*yourappname*
  class Application
    include Rake::DSL
  end
end
and
require 'rake/dsl_definition' 
before the .. LoadTask entry