# Heroku rake error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rake, dbmigrate

When I run `rake db:migrate` on Heroku, I get an error. I have no problems running it locally.

This works fine:

```
C:\unaton>rake db:migrate
```

But when I use

```
C:\unaton>heroku rake db:migrate
```

then I get the following error.

```
(in /app)
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Rake::DSL
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:8:in `<class:Ta
skLib>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:6:in `<module:R
ake>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:3:in `<top (req
uired)>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb:20:in `<top (r
equired)>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.r
ake:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/tasks.rb:15:in `block
 in <top (required)>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `each'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `<top (
required)>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in
 `initialize_tasks'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:139:in
 `load_tasks'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in
`method_missing'
/app/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `load'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1991:in `run'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181312/how-to-fix-the-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl-problem-on-heroku

Answer (score 7):

Either upgrade to rails 3.0.9 or add this to the Gemfile

gem "rake", "0.8.7"

Comment: I still ran into this problem with 3.0.9, and had to add "0.8.7" to the Gemfile.  Also, you need to run "bundle update rake" after that to regenerate your Gemfile.lock, and push the new Gemfile.lock to heroku also.

Comment: This way works for me. Before this I have tried to [add `require 'rake/dsl_definition'`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181312/how-to-fix-the-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl-problem-on-heroku) in my Rakefile but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

From http://softwaregravy.com/rake-not-backwards-compatible/

> Here’s the error:
>
> rake aborted! uninitialized constant
>   Rake::DSL
>   /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2482:in
>   `const_missing'
>   /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.1/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:8:in`
>   '
>   /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.1/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:6:in
>   `'
>
> Pin rake to 0.8.7 in your Gemfile
>
> gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
>
> Note, you’re probably already locked
>   into 0.9.X, so you need to do a:
>
> bundle update rake

Comment: The link is broken now ("The page you're looking for cannot be found").

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. But... the answer remains the same, and is essentially the same solution as the top answer. I just felt it necessary to attribute the author since it was quoted verbatim.