# rake db:migrate returns no such file to load -- rake/dsl_definition (I've searched and tried adding require 'rake/dsl_definition')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rake

My hair is all gone and I'm about to throw my new macbook through the window.

I am trying to execute the famous db:migrate command and I get the following:
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- rake/dsl_definition

I am using rake 0.8.7...it's installed and included in my gemfile.  I didn't have require 'rake/dsl_definition' in my rake file and I was getting the famous uninitialized-constant error.  Now that I have added require 'rake/dsl_definition' to my rake file I get the error above.  Anyyyyy ideas...I have searched and tried a million things with no luck...  My migrations worked 2 days ago, now suddenly they don't.  I have uninstalled rake 0.9.2 and also did a few other thing suggested in the link below, but nothing worked.r

[How to fix the uninitialized constant Rake::DSL problem on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181312/how-to-fix-the-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl-problem-on-heroku)

[heroku rake require 'rake/dsl_definition' fix not working + breaking local rake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400605/heroku-rake-require-rake-dsl-definition-fix-not-working-breaking-local-rake)

[How to fix the uninitialized constant Rake::DSL problem on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181312/how-to-fix-the-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl-problem-on-heroku)

Answer (score 1):

Having rolled back your rake to 0.8.7, you need to *remove* the `require rake/dsl-definition` line from your rakefile. You only get the uninitialised constant error with later rakes.