# Rake error: Stack level too deep

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I know this is a common question, but I just started a project with the new Rails 3.1.0 and Ruby 1.9.2 p290

On my first migrations I had already this error and I am not sure why.

```
Aurelien$ rake db:migrate --trace
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant MAJOR
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant MINOR
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant BUILD
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant NUMBERS
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:9: warning: already initialized constant VERSION
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:26: warning: already initialized constant RAKEVERSION
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/early_time.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant EARLY
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: warning: already initialized constant WINDOWS
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:28: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_RAKEFILES
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#ext already exists
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#pathmap already exists
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task_arguments.rb:73: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY_TASK_ARGS
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/invocation_chain.rb:49: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: already initialized constant RUBY
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:84: warning: already initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:143: warning: already initialized constant Commands
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:44: warning: already initialized constant ARRAY_METHODS
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:47: warning: already initialized constant MUST_DEFINE
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:51: warning: already initialized constant MUST_NOT_DEFINE
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:55: warning: already initialized constant SPECIAL_RETURN
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:61: warning: already initialized constant DELEGATING_METHODS
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:364: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PATTERNS
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:370: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PROCS
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:64: warning: already initialized constant FileList
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:65: warning: already initialized constant RakeFileUtils
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
stack level too deep
/Users/Aurelien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:162
```

I also removed the gems and re-tyring with db:reset
    source 'http://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

#gem "rspec-rails", :group => [:test, :development]

group :test do
  #gem "factory_girl_rails"
  #gem "capybara"
  #gem "guard-rspec"
  #gem "spork", "> 0.9.0.rc"
  #gem "guard-spork"
end
```

The rake commands work with `bundle exec`, but it would be nice to avoid using it.

Thank you in advance for tips and answers.

Aurelien

Comment: is there a difference between your bundled rake, and your system rake? I'd suggest that's the problem. `rake --version` vs `bundle exec rake --version`. It looks like it's trying to require the rake libraries again, and causing some sort of loop.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, but I get the same version:  
`Aurelien-Schlumbergers-MacBook-Pro:tchinchine Aurelien$ rake --version
rake, version 0.9.2
Aurelien-Schlumbergers-MacBook-Pro:tchinchine Aurelien$ bundle exec rake --version
rake, version 0.9.2
`

Comment: hmm... what if you try creating a new gemset, then bundle install, and try to rake again? Is there some crazy gem overwriting something globally? `rvm gemset create tchinchine && rvm gemset use tchinchine` otherwise, I can't think why `bundle exec rake` would be different from `rake`

Comment: See the similar question ["RoR: Rake aborted"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727898/rake-aborted-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl-on-heroku) with the reference to a [Yehuda Katz article](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right/) why to use all the time `bundle exec` together with `rake`.

Comment: Thank you Mathew and mliebelt. I guess I will keep using bundle exec, and follow Mr. Katz notes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should specifically add Rake version >= 0.9.2 in your Gemfile!
There was a bug with some Rails 3 versions where you would see strange errors like this when you use an older Rake version.

In your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rake' , '>= 0.9.2'
```

I'd also recommend you create a new gemset specifically for your application, e.g.

```
rvm gemset create yourproject
rvm gemset use yourproject
```

or:

```
rvm gemset use yourproject --default
```

for the new gemset, you might have to add "gem install rake" manually, then run "bundle install"

Using a separate gemset in addition to using your Gemfile is the best way to keep your gem versions in your project stable, and decoupled from other projects.