# Rails rake giving conflict messages (rails 3.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rvm

Abbreviated paths:

```
me@michael-laptop:~/Dropbox_not_syncd/webs/3/tdd/rubyists$ rake db:create
.../rake/version.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant MAJOR
.../rake/version.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant MINOR
.../rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant BUILD
.../rake/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant NUMBERS
.../rake/version.rb:9: warning: already initialized constant VERSION
.../rake.rb:26: warning: already initialized constant RAKEVERSION
.../rake/early_time.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant EARLY
.../rake/alt_system.rb:32: warning: already initialized constant WINDOWS
.../rake/application.rb:28: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_RAKEFILES
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#ext already exists
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#pathmap already exists
.../rake/task_arguments.rb:73: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY_TASK_ARGS
.../rake/invocation_chain.rb:49: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY
.../rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: already initialized constant RUBY
.../rake/file_utils.rb:84: warning: already initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED
.../rake/dsl_definition.rb:143: warning: already initialized constant Commands
.../rake/file_list.rb:44: warning: already initialized constant ARRAY_METHODS
.../rake/file_list.rb:47: warning: already initialized constant MUST_DEFINE
.../rake/file_list.rb:51: warning: already initialized constant MUST_NOT_DEFINE
.../rake/file_list.rb:55: warning: already initialized constant SPECIAL_RETURN
.../rake/file_list.rb:61: warning: already initialized constant DELEGATING_METHODS
.../rake/file_list.rb:364: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PATTERNS
.../rake/file_list.rb:370: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PROCS
.../rake.rb:64: warning: already initialized constant FileList
.../rake.rb:65: warning: already initialized constant RakeFileUtils
rake aborted!
stack level too deep

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Full Paths:

```
@michael-laptop:~/Dropbox_not_syncd/webs/3/tdd/rubyists$ rake db:create
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant MAJOR
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant MINOR
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant BUILD
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant NUMBERS
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:9: warning: already initialized constant VERSION
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:26: warning: already initialized constant RAKEVERSION
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/early_time.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant EARLY
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: warning: already initialized constant WINDOWS
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:28: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_RAKEFILES
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#ext already exists
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#pathmap already exists
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task_arguments.rb:73: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY_TASK_ARGS
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/invocation_chain.rb:49: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: already initialized constant RUBY
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:84: warning: already initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:143: warning: already initialized constant Commands
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:44: warning: already initialized constant ARRAY_METHODS
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:47: warning: already initialized constant MUST_DEFINE
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:51: warning: already initialized constant MUST_NOT_DEFINE
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:55: warning: already initialized constant SPECIAL_RETURN
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:61: warning: already initialized constant DELEGATING_METHODS
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:364: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PATTERNS
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:370: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PROCS
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:64: warning: already initialized constant FileList
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:65: warning: already initialized constant RakeFileUtils
rake aborted!
stack level too deep

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Have you tried the tips in [Rake error - stack level too deep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631263/rake-error-stack-level-too-deep)? And the tip to use `bundle exec rake ...` instead of `rake ...? ? See the [blog post of Yehuda Katz](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right/) for more information.

Comment: yes bundle exec worked. Thx. (see below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bundle exec rake db:migrate` should solve this error. I ran into the same thing a while ago and this solved it for me.

Comment: I dislike having to use bundle exec as I've always been able to get things working without it.  However I will accept. Will give you the check as that worked.

Comment: If you don't want to use `bundle exec`, you can probably do `gem install rake -v (version)`... basically install the same `rake` as you have bundled with your app so you'll be using your system's `rake` instead of your app's version.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, RVM no longer installs rake into the global gemset for use with each gemset for a specific ruby. This is germane because we do this so that you can install rake PER-PROJECT via the Gemfile and/or the gemset directly.

We highly encourage per-project .rvmrc files so as to isolate each project's gems to its specific gemset assignment. This keeps 'default' and/or 'global' from A) being polluted, or B) polluting other gemsets.

The only gem that should be in the 'global' gemset for each installed Ruby should be bundler.

```
rvm x.x.x@global exec rvm gemset empty && rvm x.x.x@global exec gem install bundler && rvm --create use x.x.x@mygemset && gem list -l
```

will demonstrate this quite effectively. Also, by doing it this way you effectively eliminate the need to

```
bundle exec ...
```

at all.