# Rake aborted! Uninitialized constant Rake::DSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake, gemfile

While this issue discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727898/rake-aborted-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl-on-heroku) and for Rake 0.9.0 I am using rake 0.9.2.2 and still facing the issue. By going to uninstall it I get lots of dependencies messages like:

> childprocess-0.3.1 depends on [rake (~> 0.9.2)] cucumber-1.1.4 depends
>   on [rake (>= 0.9.2)] cucumber-rails-1.2.1 depends on [rake (>=
>   0.9.2.2)] execjs-1.3.0 depends on [rake (>= 0)] execjs-1.2.12 depends on [rake (>= 0)] gherkin-2.7.7 depends on [rake (>= 0.9.2)]
>   jk-ferret-0.11.8.3 depends on [rake (>= 0)] multi_json-1.0.4 depends
>   on [rake (~> 0.9)]

What should I do then?

I have even added following in Rake:

> require 'rake/dsl_definition'
>
> require 'rake'

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

Add `gem 'rake', '0.9.2.2'` in the Gemfile;

Then add

```
require 'rake/dsl_definition'
require 'rake'
```

in the Rakefile.